# By what process is this definite integral computed?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

As part of a calculation I am following in a semiconductor devices textbook, the author asks us to consider

$$\int_0^L f(x) e^{\int_0^x f(y) dy}dx$$
for some constant $L$ and function $f$. The book says I should arrive at
$$e^{\int_0^L f(y) dy} - 1,$$
but I can't quite see how. It feels like it should be breathtakingly easy, but I proceed by parts and can't get near this. Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you aware of Fundamental Theorem of Calculus?

Comment: Try setting $u$ to be the integral. Then use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus to get $du$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that $\frac{d}{dx}\left\{e^{u(x)}\right\}=u'(x)e^{u(x)}$.

Now consider the particular function $u(x) = \int_0^x f(t)\,dt$. This $u$ is just an antiderivative of $f$, so that $u'(x) = f(x)$.

Putting it together, we have that $\frac{d}{dx}\left\{e^{\int_0^x f(t)\,dt}\right\}=f(x)e^{\int_0^x f(t)\,dt}$.

In other words, $e^{\int_0^x f(t)\,dt}$ is an antiderivative of $f(x)e^{\int_0^x f(t)\,dt}$.

Therefore, $$\int_0^Lf(x)e^{\int_0^x f(t)\,dt}\,dx = \left.e^{\int_0^x f(t)\,dt}\right|_0^L = e^{\int_0^L f(t)\,dt}-e^{\int_0^0 f(t)\,dt}$$
$$=e^{\int_0^L f(t)\,dt}-e^0$$
$$=\boxed{e^{\int_0^L f(t)\,dt}-1}$$
as claimed.

Comment: Maybe all he needed was a hint.

Comment: Thank you! I'm not sure how or why I got lost given that I was using FTC etc., but I appreciate you laying it out here.

Comment: You're welcome. Now you should try writing it out from scratch without looking. It's very useful, even though I presented it all, to work through the steps independently. Seeing doesn't mean you understand it.

Comment: @MPW, congratulations! I like your answer very much (+1).